# MySQL: LIKE and First character

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

I have two MySQL questions.

```
$query = "  SELECT
                stationname
            FROM
                stations
            WHERE
                stationname >= '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['letter']) ."' 
            ORDER BY
                stationname

";
```

Here is the first query. In the URL is a parameter set `$_GET['letter']` containing an Alphabetic character. I'm trying to select all the rows where `stationname` starts with `$_GET['letter']`. So i found this solution in an other Stackoverflow topic, but it doesn't seem to work, i get all my rows, and not just that single one. **edit** : seems it checks for all the characters in `stationname`, and not just the starting letter, how can i get that?

```
$query = "  SELECT
                stationname
            FROM
                stations
            WHERE
                stationname 
            LIKE
                    '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) ."'
";
```

Second and final question. I want to make a search engine for my website, selecting all the rows where `stationname` contains `$_POST['search']`. But when i have 2 rows, one for example called `cheese` and the other one called `cheese2`, and i search for `cheese`, only `cheese` get selected, and when i search for `cheese2`, only `cheese2` will get selected. Is there any way to select both `cheese` and `cheese2`?

Comment: `LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) ."%'`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) supports wildcards.  `%` means any number of characters (including zero), and `_` means any one character`

```
stationname LIKE 'cheese%'
```

This would match `cheese` and `cheese2`.

You can use the `%` for the first issue too.

```
stationname LIKE 'a%'
```

This will find all words that start with `'a'`.

Comment: @Thew: You mean for the starting character?  Does `stationname LIKE 'a%'` not work?

Answer (score 6):

> I'm trying to select all the rows where stationname starts with $_GET['letter']

MySQL has a [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function which seems to be what you're looking for. So basically we extract the first letter of the `stationname` and compare it agains your letter:

```
 where left(stationname, 1) = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['letter']) . "'";
```

> Is there any way to select both cheese and cheese2?

Well here the solution is a little smelly, as you should check whether `cheese` is contained in `cheese2` and also whether `cheese2` is contained in `cheese`. Try this:

```
where stationname like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) .
  "%' OR '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) .
  "' like concat('%', stationname, '%')";
```

Answer (score 3):

for second.

```
 $query = "   SELECT
                        stationname
                    FROM
                        stations
                    WHERE
                        stationname 
                    LIKE
                        '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) ."%'
        ";
```

Comment: @Thew query above only checks starting chars.

Answer (score 1):

The text wildcard in MySQL is %, so for your first query you would probably want:

```
$query = "    SELECT
                    stationname
                FROM
                    stations
                WHERE
                    stationname LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['letter']) ."%' 
                ORDER BY
                    stationname
    ";
```

And for your second query:

```
$query = "   SELECT
                    stationname
                FROM
                    stations
                WHERE
                    stationname 
                LIKE
                    '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']) ."%'
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR Tel Number

5 finds that the first character

```
$Sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE TEL REGEXP '^[5]' LIMIT 0,500";
```